# Fields extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to resolve this exercise, but I'm little confused. Let $K/F$ be a extension of fields, where $K=F(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is transcendent over $F$, I proved that all elements of $K-F$ are be transcendents, but I need to prove that $F(\alpha)/F(\beta)$ is a finite extension, where $\beta \in K-F$. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $\beta$ is a rational function of $\alpha$, that is, $\beta=\frac{p(\alpha)}{q(\alpha)}$, where $p,q\in F[X]$.